Mipmapping with holoviews
I have a problem with displaying my 1D data (in this case, an ECG). Commonly, ECG has its data printed on mm paper, with 25mm per second for example for the speed of printing is common. Now, when I want to visualize a bigger datum, lets say 400 seconds, there will literally be 10000 lines on the screen, with holoviews HLine it will just be a red blob (as seen in the zoomed out image). How can I make the lines either more sparse (so e.g. only spaced at 1/50th the density) or something when I am zoomed out? I checked RangeXY, but I did not see how that would help in any way here. The data looks fine when I zoom in, thats pretty much the way a real ECG would be printed.
What I would look for is something like mipmapping from CG, but I have not been able to find anything to do so.



Try apply_when, to make some or all the lines invisible (alpha=0) when you zoom out.
